# Add subprograms in Ada

Tags: ada

For this code, I need help with writing subprograms "Put" and "Make_Price". Subprogram "Put" should take a  "Separator" parameter (a character that separates dollars from cents with ':' and ','). And subprogram "Make_Price" should take two Integers and then return dollars and cents (as it shows in the main program, P1, and P2).

```
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;              use Ada.Float_Text_IO;
with Ada.Text_IO;                    use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;            use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

Procedure Price is
type Price_Type is
record
Dollar,Cents: Integer;
end record;
P1, P2 : Price_Type;

procedure Put(Item: out Price_Type;
Item_2: out Character) is
Separator:Character;
begin
Put_Line(Item.Dollar, Separator); --Error: too many arguments in call to 
--"Put_Line"
Put(Item.Cents);
end Put;
  
function Make_price(Left, Right: in Price_Type) return Price_Type is
L,R: Integer; 
begin
L:= Left.Dollar; 
R:= Right.Cents;
return L;     --Error: expected type "Price_Type"
end Make_price;

begin
P1 := Make_Price(19, 50);
P2 := Make_Price(10, 00);
Put_Line("First price: ");
Put(P1, Separator => ':'); --Prints out with ':' 
New_Line;
Put_Line("Second price: ");
Put(P2, Separator => ','); -- Prints out with ',' 
New_Line;
end Price;
```

Comment: Is the purpose of this program to handle dollars and cents or is the purpose to learn how to implement and manipulate a record?

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in formatting money output look at the package Ada.Text_IO.Editing described in Appendix F.3.3 of the Ada Language Reference Manual. An example of using this package to provide differing radix marks is shown below.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Text_IO.Editing; use Ada.Text_IO.Editing;

procedure Main is
   type Money is delta 0.01 digits 8;
   package Money_IO is new Decimal_Output(Num => Money);
   use Money_IO;
   
   P1 : Picture := To_Picture("-$$$_$$$.$$");

   price_1 : Money := 19.50;
   price_2 : Money := 10.00;
begin
   Put(File => Standard_Output, Item => Price_1, Pic => P1, Radix_Mark => ':');
   New_Line;
   Put(File => Standard_Output, Item => Price_2, Pic => P1,  Radix_Mark => ',');
   New_Line;
end Main;
```

The output of the above program is:

```
 $19:50
 $10,00
```

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure `Put`:

```
procedure Put(Item: out Price_Type;
              Item_2: out Character) is
   Separator:Character;
begin
   Put_Line(Item.Dollar, Separator);
   Put(Item.Cents);
end Put;
```

- Why do you use `out` parameters? These are obviously `in` mode (which is the default, so it’s common practice to omit it).
- `Separator` isn’t initialized. From the way you use it below, the second parameter should be named `Separator`.
- The way the procedure is called, and analogy with `Ada.Text_IO`, indicates that the procedure shouldn’t output any new lines at all.
- There’s no `Put_Line` which takes an `Integer` and a `Character`.

Your procedure `Make_Price`:

```
function Make_price(Left, Right: in Price_Type) return Price_Type is
   L,R: Integer;
begin
   L:= Left.Dollar;
   R:= Right.Cents;
   return L;
end Make_price;
```

- `Left` should be named `Dollar` (well, I’d’ve named it `Dollars`, but there you go). `Right` should be named `Cents`. Both should be of type `Integer` (as shown by the way the function is called below).
- You’re trying to return a `Price_Type`, so `return L;` can’t be right. You need to make the record; `(Dollar => Dollar, Cents => Cents)` compiles, but `Price_Type'(Dollar => Dollar, Cents => Cents)` is better.

Getting the output formatted better would be the subject of a different question. Or see [Jim’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64658247/40851).